# Flutter: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method printPdf on channel net.nfet.printing)

Tags: flutter, pdf, printing, pos, flutter-desktop

guys!
I am developing a desktop POS application for a shop. The application should have a feature to print some docs and barcodes. I have used [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) package to generate pdfs, but I am having a trouble with installing and using the [priting](https://pub.dev/packages/printing) package on Windows.

The main problem is with isntallation. In the docs, it says you should add the following lines in

> CMakeLists.txt

file:

```
...
set(PDFIUM_VERSION "4929" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(PDFIUM_ARCH "x64" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
...
```

1. I am very confused in which CMakeLists.txt I shall put, because flutter's windows folder includes multiple files with the same name and extension. (*windows\CMakeLists.txt, windows\runner\CMakeLists.txt, windows\flutter\CMakeLists.txt*)
2. I have put the same piece of code into these different files, but none of them worked.
3. It always gives some errors like below:
   [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCk6P.png)

The thing I wanted to accomplish is to just print a generated PDF:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9aH0.png)

Comment: Which means I shall have to install pdf application for my application to work?

Answer (score 4):

I'm having the same issue

What I do is

- Flutter clean
- Flutter pub get
- Uninstall the previous application
- Run the app again

And it worked

Answer (score -1):

go to your terminal and type the following commands.

1. Flutter clean
2. Flutter pub get
3. now close the app
4. build the app again
   hope this works for you. thanks.

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as the other one